# Trying to define types with variadic templates

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates

I'm brand new to variadic templates, so bear with me here.

I'm trying to bring my dimensional analysis library into the 21st century and up to C++11. I'd like the ability to define a tuple type, not an instance. This is basically what I want to state:

```
using velocity_dimension = make_dimension<1, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0>;
```

The result should equivalent to:

```
using velocity_dimension = std::tuple<std::ratio<1>, std::ratio<0>, std::ratio<-1>, std::ratio<0>, std::ratio<0>, std::ratio<0>, std::ratio<0>>;
```

I'm struggling to wrap my brain around variadic templates and how to get the interface I want. I've been trying to experiment with:

```
template<typename T, typename ...Args>
using make_list = std::tuple < std::ratio<T>, make_list<Args>...>> ;
```

Which I think just illustrates how much I don't understand how these things are supposed to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want something that takes a variable number of integers, not types, so there should be no `typename` in the template parameter list.

Similarly in `std::ratio<T>` the template argument should be an integer, not a type.

Your recursive  `make_list` won't work, because you cannot specialize an alias template, so there is no way to terminate the recursion. You could do something like that with a class template and provide a partial specialization to terminate the recursion, but there's no need to do that.

I think you just want:

```
template<int... I>
  using make_dimension = std::tuple<std::ratio<I>...>;
```

This takes a parameter pack of integers, then expands it into a list of `std::ratio<>` specializations and wraps the lot in a tuple.

The pack expansion pattern here is `std::ratio<I>...` which means each element `i` in the parameter pack `I` will be replaced with `std::ratio<i>`, so if the pack is `1, 2, 3` then the expansion is `std::ratio<1>, std::ratio<2>, std::ratio<3>`